# Swift/ObjC: Attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, swift5

I'm following a tutorial on Udemy about Swift and even though my code is exactly the same as the teacher's, my app crashes.

It uses Firebase to create users and log them in.

My issue is when I try to create a new user, it crashes with this error:

```
"*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]"
```

After looking into my code, it seems that the problems comes from the registerUser function:

```
    static func registerUser(withCredentials credentials: AuthCredentials, completion: @escaping((Error?) -> Void)) {
    
    Service.uploadImage(image: credentials.profileImage) { imageUrl in
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: credentials.email, password: credentials.password) { (result, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("DEBUG: Error signing user up, \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            
            guard let uid = result?.user.uid else { return }
            
            let data = ["email": credentials.email,
                        "name": credentials.name,
                        "imageUrl": imageUrl,
                        "uid": uid,
                        "age": 18] as [String : Any]
            
            Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(uid).setData(data, completion: completion)
        }
    }
}
```

which is called here:

```
    @objc func handleRegisterUser() {
    guard let email = emailTextField.text else { return }
    guard let name = nameTextField.text else { return }
    guard let password = passwordTextField.text else { return }
    guard let profileImage = self.profileImage else { return }

    let credentials = AuthCredentials(email: email, password: password, name: name, profileImage: profileImage)

    **AuthService.registerUser(withCredentials: credentials) { error in
        if let error = error {
            print("DEBUG: Error signing user up, \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }**

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me with that by guiding me in the right direction on where should I look?
I tried searching StackOverFlow but the closest thread I could find was from 6 years ago and I didn't find any answer there.

Thanks a lot for your help,

Jihaysse

Comment: imageUrl is nil in your case ...

Comment: It is actually the `name` that is `nil`, since `objects[1]` denotes the second object.

Answer (score 0):

I think imageUrl is nil in your case. Change this function like this to see whats issue

```
static func registerUser(withCredentials credentials: AuthCredentials, completion: @escaping((Error?) -> Void)) {
        
        Service.uploadImage(image: credentials.profileImage) { imageUrl in
            let urlString: String? = imageUrl
            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: credentials.email, password: credentials.password) { (result, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("DEBUG: Error signing user up, \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    return
                }
                
                guard let uid = result?.user.uid else { return }
                guard let geturl = urlString else { print("url is nil"); return}
                guard let getName = credentials.name else { print("name is nil"); return}
                
                let data = ["email": credentials.email,
                            "name": credentials.name,
                            "imageUrl": imageUrl,
                            "uid": uid,
                            "age": 18] as [String : Any]
                
                Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(uid).setData(data, completion: completion)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work, same error :/ Thank you though! But you may be right, I think the problem comes from imageUrl because the teacher already uploaded image on Firebase (which is pointless because I want that every user can upload image and then use it on their profile) => That may answer why the exact same code works with the teacher but not with me.

Comment: check it out now